# Can't install MatPlotLib for python 3 Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am very new to coding and don't understand install processes. I am using Python 3.7.0 on Max OSX El Capitan.  I want to install matplotlib but I tried this in terminal :

```
$ pip install matplotlib
```

and it gave me an error that :

```
192-168-1-107:~ Ada1$ pip install matplotlib Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.5 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)  
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)     
Collecting tornado (from matplotlib) Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/tornado/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tornado (from matplotlib) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tornado (from matplotlib)
```

I also tried :

> $ sudo pip install matplotlib

but same error and python gives the error it is not installed. Help?

Comment: are you sure you have pip installed? Make sure you follow the notes in this link https://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#osx-notes

Comment: If you're still getting errors, put the error code here so that we can better help you

Comment: I'm not sure I have pip installed. How do I check?

Comment: "gave me an error that something was missing" - this is an antipod of proper question requesting for help

Comment: I have pasted below the error message, it is missing tornado

Comment: May I ask to cast your vote again for the answer?

Comment: What's the output of `pip --version`?

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are 3 possible causes I can see:

- conflict of python 3 or 2 versions (most liekly)
- OSX-specific bugs (needs a newer pip version as discussed [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5236#issuecomment-381678057)),
- you are behind firewal (you can disable SSL by adding flags to pip command)

To make sure you are installing to python 3 you can use:

```
pip3 install -U matplotlib
```

Vertual environments and `pipenv`, conda and possibly [poetry](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry) are your friends to achive greater isolation of python project setups in the future.